# Como gravar um arquivo .xlsx permanentemente, usando a biblioteca ClosedXML?

Tags: c#, microsoft-excel

Quando se executa o código para simulação, percebe-se que ele está alterando o arquivo *teste.xlsx*
conforme o esperado, porém, ao fechar a execução o mesmo não salva as alterações, pois,
ao executar o programa novamente ele iniciará um arquivo novo e não puxará a base já alterada.

---

---

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (var workbook = new XLWorkbook())
        {
            string DataEmprestimo;
            string DataDevolucao;
            var row = 1;
            var col = 1;
            var linha = row;
            var coluna = col;
            int cont = 2;

            var planilha = workbook.Worksheets.Add("Planilha1");

            planilha.Cell(linha, coluna).Value = "Equipamento";
            var range = planilha.Range("A1"); 
            range.Merge().Style.Font.SetBold().Font.FontSize = 12;
            planilha.Columns().AdjustToContents();

            linha = linha + 1;

            for (cont = 2; cont <= 20000; cont++)
            {
                var Equipamento = planilha.Cell("A" + cont.ToString()).Value.ToString();
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Equipamento) == true)
                {
                    linha = cont;
                    planilha.Cell(linha, coluna).Value = textBox1.Text;
                    
                    break;
                }
            }
            /*
            while (true)
            {
                var Equipamento = planilha.Cell("A" + linha.ToString()).Value.ToString();
                
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Equipamento))
                {
                    break;
                }

            }
            */
            
            planilha.Cell("B3").Value = textBox2.Text;
            planilha.Cell("C2").Value = textBox3.Text;
            planilha.Cell("D2").Value = textBox4.Text;
            planilha.Cell("E2").Value = textBox5.Text;
            planilha.Cell("F2").Value = textBox6.Text;
            planilha.Cell("G2").Value = textBox7.Text;

            DataEmprestimo = CalEmp.SelectionRange.Start.ToShortDateString();
            planilha.Cell("H2").Value = DataEmprestimo;

            
            DataDevolucao = CalDev.SelectionRange.Start.ToShortDateString();
            planilha.Cell("I2").Value = DataDevolucao;



            MessageBox.Show("Equipamento cadastrado");
            workbook.SaveAs(@"c:\data\teste.xlsx");

            //Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo(@"c:\data\teste.xlsx") { UseShellExecute = true });
            workbook.Dispose();
            
            
        }

        
    }

    private void groupBox1_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        
    }

    private void btnSair_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Close();
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo(@"c:\data\teste.xlsx") { UseShellExecute = true });
    }
}
```

Comment: Não consegui entender, eu testei o seu código e está funcionando perfeitamente. fechei a aplicação, abri novamente e os dados continuam salvos no arquivo... Você poderia detalhar melhor sobre o que está acontecendo? Versão da biblioteca do ClosedXml também

Comment: Tente cadastrar mais de um equipamento, ele está sobrescrevendo o arquivo existente.

Comment: Ok, então você cria o arquivo uma vez com algumas informações, e quando executa novamente com informações diferentes, você quer que ele gere um segundo arquivo? Porque se você passa o mesmo arquivo, ele irá sobrescrever mesmo

Comment: Eu quero utilizar o arquivo.xlsx como um banco de dados, quero cadastrar e gravar na planilha, e consultar posteriormente.